# how to send unicode character with serial port in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

how can I send unicode character(16bit) to serial port in C#? Data bit rate for serial is maximum is 8 bit and I need to send 16 bit character.

Edit
When I send 'ş', it is sent as '_'

```
byte[] bt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ş");
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bt);
serialport.write(str);
```

Comment: You've got a wide choice of Encodings (UTF7, UTF8, UTF16). The point is, what does the other side understand/expect?

Comment: how do you know it is send as '_'? Is this what you receive -> Your decoding the message wrong. Can you post some code how you send it and how you receive it.

Comment: @PoweRoy I will post the code in a minute

Comment: @PoweRoy the device that is connected via serialport is sending sms message. I receive '-' from sms when I send 'ş'

Comment: I hope you are not using this only on the sending side. It looks like you are converting it to bytes then back to a string and then send it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do at least two things:

- Agree between the sending and receiving end which order you're going to send the two bytes of the pair.
- Agree some system for identifying whether the next byte that arrives is the first or second byte of a pair (you might need some kind of packet structure or line-delimiter)

At some point, if you agree to send LSB first, you could use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(<mystring>)`, but you will still need to be clear about the framing (the second point above).

You would probably be better using UTF8, rather than UCS16 ('unicode'), as this will deal with all these issues for you.

Comment: I read the string into byte array as unicode encoded, then write the byte to UTF8 encoded string, then send that string. But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Just send your data as a stream of bytes, one by one.

Comment: it needs to be sent as string.

Comment: @zonu a unicode string is a string of bytes with 2 bytes per character.

Comment: @AB Kolan, yeah my bad, but besides the point that it's just sending the raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class provided by .NET Framework and you could use `Write` method

Syntax:

```
public void Write(
    string text
)
```

Example:

`SerialPort.Write("love, peace and chocolates");`

[SerialPort.Write method on msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8.aspx)

Comment: I need to send something like that("şüisdfiüüÇ")

Comment: He is using SerialPort.Write (see code in edited/updated question)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
byte[] bt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ş");
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bt);
serialport.write(str);
```

But shouldn't you be doing it differently:

```
//Sender
byte[] bt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ş");
serialport.write(bt);

//Receiver
byte[4] bt; //Unicode characters could be up to 4 bytes.
SerialPort.Read(bt, 0, 4);
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bt);
```

Havent tested/compiled it but this is a rough idea.

Or use the encoding property of the SerialPort

```
//Sender
serialport.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
serialport.write("ş");

//Receiver
SerialPort.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string line = SerialPort.ReadLine();
```